# Assign new values to each index of a string

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to assign some values to the characters:

```
'a'==12
'b'==22
'C'==15
'D'==29
```

My function called sumassign(s) asks for the user to input the above characters and I should return the sum of the above characters, the expected output is shown below

```
sumassign("abC")
49
```

My codes are below.

```
def sumassign(s):
    return sum(i=='a'==12 or i=='b'==22 or i=='C'==15 or i=='D'==29 for i in s)
```

When I try to use my code, it returns 0 instead of the sum

```
sumassign("abC")
0
```

Answer (score 2):

This is what [data structures](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html) like dictionaries are for. If you want to map a character to a value, the most common was to do it is with a dict. If you do that, everything else gets *much* easier. For example:

```
mapping = {
    'a': 12,
    'b': 22,
    'C': 15,
    'D': 29
}

def sumassign(s):
    ''' lookup up the value of every item in s an take the sum '''
    return sum(mapping[d] for d in s)
               
sumassign("abC")
# 49
```

It's worth spending time to at least have a basic understanding of lists and dictionaries before going too much further. They are **essential** to writing idiomatic Python.

Answer (score -2):

You can separate the characters and the numbers into arrays and use a for loop to iterate through every number in the numbers array and add each number to a variable named sum:

```
def main():
    letters = ['a', 'b', 'C', 'D']
    numbers = [12, 22, 15, 29]
    sum = 0
    for i in (numbers):
        sum += i
    print(sum)

main()
```